# Variance- covariance matrix

Tags: statistics, regression, statistical-inference, sampling

Consider $H$ denotes hat matrix and $e$ denotes residual.

In the book `Applied regression Analysis` by Draper/Smith, it is written that :

#### $\mathbb V(e_i)$ is given by the $i$th diagonal element $(1-h_{ii})$, and $\mathbb cov(e_i,e_j)$ is given by the $(i,j)$th element $(-h_{ij})$ of the matrix $(I-H)\sigma^2$

But my contradiction is arising here that :

$\mathbb V(e_i)$ is given by the $i$th diagonal element $(1-h_{ii})\sigma^2$ of the matrix $(I-H)\sigma^2$

and

$\mathbb cov(e_i,e_j)$ is given by the $(i,j)$th element $(-h_{ij})\sigma^2$ of the matrix $(I-H)\sigma^2$

Can you please explain me why is the contradiction arising ?

Comment: What ist your question, your problem ?

Comment: @calculus $\mathbb V(e_i)$ is not given by the $i$th diagonal element
 $(1-h_{ii})$ of the matrix $(I-H)\sigma^2$ rather by $(1-h_{ii})\sigma^2$ .There is a $\sigma^2$ here.

Comment: Sorry I didn´t get your problem, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of $\sigma^2$ in your formulae is correct. I suspect a normalization $\sigma = 1$: this is a point to check in the reference-unfortunately I have no access to it-.  In any case I would define some context. Let  $Y=X\theta+\epsilon$ be a regression line with

$$E[\epsilon]=0,~~\operatorname{Cov}(\epsilon)=E[\epsilon\epsilon^T]:=\sigma^2 I_n,$$

where $I_n$ denotes the identity matrix in $n$-dimension and $\operatorname{Cov}$ the covariance matrix. Using LS estimation, one arrives at the estimator $\hat \theta$ for the regression coefficients $\theta$, with

$$\hat \theta = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T Y, $$
and
$$\hat Y = X\hat \theta:=PY.$$
The residuals $R$ are then

$$R:= Y-\hat Y =(1-P)Y,$$

with $E[R]=E[Y]-E[\hat Y]= 0$ and

$$\operatorname{Cov}(R)=(1-P)\operatorname{Cov}(Y)(1-P)^T = (1-P)\sigma^2 I_n (1-P)^T=\sigma^2(1-P) $$

as $(1-P)$ is nilpotent due to nilpotency of $P$, and $(1-P)^T=(1-P)$.
For additional details I refer to this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21499/what-is-the-variance-covariance-matrix-of-the-ols-residual-vector) and this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).